# MAC OS QuickTime framework SGNewChannel fails for 10.8.4 but works for 10.8.5?

Tags: macos, video-capture, quicktime

With reference to this question mentioned here [SGNewChannel error -9405 on Mac 10.9.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20669326/sgnewchannel-error-9405-on-mac-10-9-1), I am facing the same problem with my code but what's weird for me is that if fails for MAC OSX Version 10.8.4 (On MacBook Air). I have another MacBook with version 10.8.5 and the code works good.

The only difference I notice is with the camera. On 10.8.5 I have the camera named as "Build-in iSight" while on 10.8.4, I have the camera name as "FaceTime HD Camera".

Has anyone encountered this problem with this camera and the OS Version ?

Please guide as to what are the other alternatives possible, or what are the potential solutions to this problem.

I googled much but could not found any solutions / alternatives to get around this problem.

So I request someone with the knowledge to guide me past the problem.

Thanks & Regards

LazyCoder7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with the particular version of MAC OS 10.8.4. There is a bug which prevents FaceTime HD camera on MacBook Air to be used by certain application.

Details of the update can be found at 
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5815.

Updating the OS version to 10.8.5 will do the trick for me, but I wonder what would happen if I upgrade it to 10.9 ??

Thus, so far so good. Will update to the latest version and test it.

Thanks & Regards,

LazyCoder7.